# MSWord breaking Hard Link

Tags: windows, ms-word, hardlink, mklink

**Question:**
Is there any option to work on an MSWORD file with a Hard Link (mklink /h) to another directory?

**What I've experienced:**
After creating a *[Hard Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* of a `.docx` file onto a different directory, modifying either the original document or the "linked" one results in a complete desynchronization.

**Possible cause:**
MSWord creates a copy of the file while being modified and then replaces the original by it. Breaking the *Hard Link*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Possible cause:
>   MSWord creates a copy of the file while being modified and then replaces the original by it. Breaking the Hard Link.

Yes, it is "by design". I think that there is no solution.

A workaround could be save docx in a separate folder and create *directory junction* with *mklink /j*. It works as expected.